# instagram authorized apps revoked without user intervention

Tags: authentication, authorization, instagram

I have authorized an app for my instagram account and listed under the manage clients page.

However, it seems like the access gets revoked every now and then (the app no longer shows up in manage clients).

Are there any scenarios during which the access would be revoked for an authorized app without the user going in to manually revoke it?

Comment: what does your app do ?

Comment: I have had this happen multiple times on a client's project. I've reauthorized our app at least 5 times only to find it mysteriously revoked after a month or two.